# How to stop grid view from creating more rows

Tags: c#-4.0, gridview

I am creating grid view through data adapter and all columns and rows are created from data base but problem occurs that when rows all rows are created there comes another empty row i want to stop that row to be generated and when i click and some value in that extra row another new row is created i want to stop all extra rows how to do this any help???

this is the grid view code i am using

```
            conn.ConnectionString = s;
            conn.Open();
            dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, s);
            dTable = new DataTable();
            DataView myDataView = dTable.DefaultView;
            dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
            BindingSource bndSource = new BindingSource();
            bndSource.DataSource = dTable;
            dataGrid.DataSource = bndSource;
            dataGrid.Columns["StudentId"].ReadOnly = true;
            dataGrid.Columns["StudentName"].ReadOnly = true;
            conn.Close();
```

Comment: Can you please share your declarative markup and databinding routine for the `GridView`? (Feel free to obfuscate column names and connection strings)

Comment: Now i have updated my question i guess this is what you wanted??

Comment: Part of it. :) Would you kindly also update your question with the declarative markup for the `GridView` or `DataGrid` with the rows you are clicking on (the part with `<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">`)?

Comment: I am using windows form application so no asp code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `AllowUserToAddRows` to `false`.